# align text to right in td tag

Tags: css

align the Date to extreme right in the `td` box using `float:right;`
it's working for chrome but not for mozilla firefox....how to align Date to extreme right in the image below?
the position of Date & size of `<hr/>` is changing with the length of content.

i want to keep the heading at left and Date at right in the same line for mozilla.

[image: aligning in mozilla]

the code used:

```
<table id='cs'>
<tr>
<td>
<font size='4' id='heading'><b><U>heading</U></b></font>
<font size='2' style='float:right;'><i><b >Date: </b>date</i></font><br/>
Test Content<br/><hr/>
Signature<br/>
</td></tr></table>
```

The id cs has below rules:

```
#cs{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 4px 17px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f0f4fc;
}
```

id Heading has below rules:

```
#heading
{
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Unless you show us the styles and html code you are following, its hard to tell something.

Comment: You should use CSS to style your text instead of using all of those HTML tags like <b>, <u> and <i>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Skovy mentioned in his comment, try to avoid your styling within html tags like you did.

Also the font-tag is deprecated.

I have written an example which solves your issue using CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #cs {
                border: 2px solid black;
                padding: 4px 17px;
                width: 100%;
                float:right;
                margin-right: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                background: #f0f4fc;
            }
            .post-content {
                <!-- style your content here -->
            }
            .post-header {
                float: left;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .post-date {
                float: right;
                font-size: 0.7em;
            }
            .post-date .label {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="cs">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="post-header">
                        Test post
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-date">
                        <span class="label">Date: </span>12.12.1212
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both"/>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        My Content
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VcAJR/).

Answer (score 2):

You should try like this.

```
 <td align='right'>date<td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class called .right to your css with text-align set to right, by the way you should ditch the font tags and do that via css

```
<style type="text/css">
 .right { text-align: right; }
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="right">stuff that I want right aligned</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to align various content in one td only. so can't use many td for different locations in the box.

Comment: So you want to have a multicolumn layout within a TD? A table may not be the right solution then. Tables are for tabular data, if it is layout you are working on, you should use DIVs. However, the same .right class would work for aligning to the right in a DIV layout. Make sure you throw float:left; on each column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since your content is in a table for whatever reason, wouldn't it be reasonable to put the date in another table column and align it to the right within that column via CSS class?

```
<table id='cs'>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <h2 class='heading'>".$heading."</h2>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class='date'><strong>Date: </strong>".$date."</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can float the class to the right, or align the text to the right.

Comment: i want to align various content in one td only. so can't use many td for different locations in the box.