# Align text input in <td> to right in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am trying to align the Text Input to the right and for some reason it is not doing this.

I have used  `style="text-align: right"` in `<td>`

See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31200/

Code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Field 1</th>
      <th style="text-align:right">Field 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text 1</td>

      <td style="text-align: right">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right">
          <input style="width:60px" type="number" class="form-control" value="test">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the '<td>Text 1</td>' to be aligned to the right? or the '<input style="width:60px" type="number" class="form-control" value="test">'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086468/align-text-to-right-in-td-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [align text to right in td tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086468/align-text-to-right-in-td-tag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No extra CSS is needed** just use Bootstrap `pull-right`:

https://jsfiddle.net/cp1tvuj3/

```
<div class="form-group">
          <input style="width:60px" type="number" class="form-control pull-right" value="test">
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cp1tvuj3/)

`text-right` won't work because the `form-control` is `display: block`

The original question was for Bootstrap 3. In Bootstrap 4, [pull-right is now **float-right**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/left-align-and-right-align-within-div-in-bootstrap/18672475#18672475).

Comment: `pull-right` has been replaced by `float-right` in Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities.

Answer (score 2):

add inline-block to your div element, by default the div is a block element so it takes the complete width of its parent

```
 <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right;display:inline-block;">
          <input style="width:60px" type="number" class="form-control" value="test">
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/y9fvo4dj/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like just adding `float: right;` does the trick, see

```css
url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Field 1</th>
      <th style="text-align:right">Field 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text 1</td>      
      <td style="text-align: right">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right; float:right">
          <input style="width:60px" type="number" class="form-control" value="test">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the div around the input field inside your td a style of

```
display:inline-block;
```

also fixes your problem without having any floats to potentially break other things.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31202/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap class ie. "pull-right"
find the code fiddle :

```
    `https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31204/e`
```

Answer (score 0):

These two solutions worked for me with a **Bootstrap 4** table:

Either:

```
<td>
    <div class="float-right">
        <input>
    </div>
</td>
```

Or:

```
<td class="text-right">
    <div class="d-inline-flex">
        <input>
    </div>
</td>
```