# BASH: How to extract text from URLs between START / STOP pattern

Tags: bash

For a bunch of URLs I'd like to extract a YEAR, f.e. 2022, which appears between these tags, f.e.:

```
<td class="text" style="border-right:0;">
2022
</td>
```

How to store '2022' locally, without storing the webpage here?

Comment: I don't know what your question is, clear it first,  what do you want to do, store page? want a pattern ? you are talking about about extracting from URL and giving HTML, where do you get HTML? Is this a webpage? what is this?

Comment: Using bash, I'd like to call webpages one by one from a longer list of URLs. The bash-script should extract (sed? grep? awk?) the year between the tags <td> ... </td> as shown in OP and store the number locally.

Comment: it needs concreate example, scenario.. your scenario/question is so general

Comment: As similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086468/align-text-to-right-in-td-tag/18086972#18086972  
Imagine START and STOP pattern as
<div class="post-header"> and </div>.  
I need to store "Test post" locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple sample code. It gives the idea, you may update the sed -n according to your new search key.

**index.html (that u mentioned in the post):**

```
<td class="text" style="border-right:0;">2022</td>
```

**Sample Code with Bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash

urls=(
    "file:/home/<username>/index.html"
    # "URL2"
)
extract_year() {
    url="$1"
    html_content=$(curl -s "$url")
    year=$(echo "$html_content" | sed -n 's/.*<td class="text" style="border-right:0;">\([0-9]\{4\}\)<\/td>.*/\1/p' | head -1)
    # store the year in a file
    if [ -n "$year" ]; then
        echo "$year" >> years.txt
    else
        echo "Year not found for $url"
    fi
}

for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    extract_year "$url"
done
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parser to work with XML files.

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//td[@class="text"][@style="border-right:0;"])' 1.html | xargs
```